# Tkinter moving GUI because of length of label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple program that moves files depending on its file type and its name. I have made all the GUI. Heres the code.

```
# Imports
from pathlib import Path
from os import path
import json
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
# Imports

file = ""
file_location = ""


def downloads_folder() -> str: # Returnes the users Download folder
    return str(path.join(Path.home(), "Downloads"))

def tkinter_init(r): # Makes GUI for Tkinter window
    r.title("PyFM")
    r.resizable(False, False)

    # Initialize GUI
    l = Label(r, text = "Enter file type or file name: ")
    fileInput = Entry(r)
    text = StringVar()
    fileLocationLabel = Label(r, textvariable=text)
    text.set("File Location: None")
    fileLocation = Button(r, text = "Add File Location", command = lambda: add_file_location(text))
    done = Button(r, text = "Done", command = lambda: doneFunc())

    # Adds GUI to screen
    l.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "w")
    fileInput.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "w")
    fileLocation.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "w")
    fileLocationLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "w")
    done.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = "e")

def add_file_location(stringVar): # Makes a file lcoation popup and changes varible file_location to the file location.
    print("Add file location clicked")
    file_location = filedialog.askdirectory()
    stringVar.set(f"File Location: {file_location}")
    print(f"File location: {file_location}")

def doneFunc():
    print("Done button clicked")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open("data.json", "r")
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    r = Tk()
    tkinter_init(r)
    r.mainloop()
```

The GUI looks just fine until I add a file location. The label changes and other GUI in the same column get squeezed. Here are the photos.

Without any file location:

[image: Photo of my GUI]

But once I add a file location, the text box gets moved and so does the button.

[image: Photo of my GUI]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `columnspan` option of the `.grid()` on the label to expand its content.

Answer (score 0):

Use `columnspan` option of the `.grid()` on the label to expand its content. – [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668)